# How to get value in html

Tags: html, flash, find

The game is in flash.
Link: http://www.miniclip.com/games/bounzy-2/pt/

I need get the value, exactly, the "Score".

This is posible?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the flash game to communicate with javascript on the page, I believe.

Comment: I know the game uses it to store: "this.score".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need to be able to modify the code of the game itself if you have access to it. It won't be able to show the scores on the page through a simple src= unless miniclip has an API that supports page interaction.